# select n rows and return a row

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join

a have sql table like this :

```
id          day            name_id_fk
1            1                  1
2            2                  1
3            4                  1
4            3                  1
```

I want select a row like this :

```
day
1|2|4|3
```

Comment: Why do you need the result in that form?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question. Why the pipes?

Comment: I have two table  'name' and 'day' a want select a name and all day for this name in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select group_concat(day,'|')
from your_table
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fd1e7/5)

Comment: I want decision on day . i SELECT CASE when  day IS 0 THEN  'SA' else  'fr' ....... END As hdays FROM  daytable . i want this result su|mo|we|tu . plz help me

Answer (score -2):

Try this Sql ...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols=STUFF((SELECT distinct '|' + CAST( yourcolumnname  AS VARCHAR)
              from  
              (
                SELECT yourcolumnname FROM yourtablename
              ) a
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')        
SELECT @cols
```

Or You can try this...

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cols=''
SELECT @cols=@cols+ cast (yourcolumnname AS VARCHAR)+'|' FROM yourtablename
SELECT  substring(@cols,0,len(@cols))
```

Comment: I work by Sqlite i think Sqlite don't support STUFF !

Comment: don't work:
could not prepare statement (1 near "DECLARE": syntax error) 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fd1e7/10